# 100% height of browser

Tags: html, css

How do I get my 100% height divs to go full height of the browser when I have to scroll down. When I load my page the divs fill the browser window but when I have to scroll the 100% height divs do not go any further, leaving a white space below.

HTML

```
<header>
</header>

<section id="sidebar">
</section>

<section id="main-container">
</section>

</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body { width:100%;height:100%; overflow:auto;}

body{
margin:0;
min-height:100%; 
height:100%; 
width:100%;
padding:0;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
color:#484848;
overflow-y:scroll;
}

#wrapper{
width:100%;
height:100%;
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
margin:0;
}

header{
width:100%;
height:10%;
min-height:80px;
position:relative;
}

#sidebar{
display: inline-block;
width:20%;
min-width:170px;
height:90%;
min-height:90%;
position:relative;
}

#main-container{
display: inline-block;
margin-left:1px;
width:78%;
height:90%;
margin-right:0.5%;
vertical-align:top;
position:relative;
}
```

I've so far tried everything I can think of.

Comment: Is that all of your html??

Comment: Maybe you can use `position:fixed`, this would let the div 100% of height and it would stay fixed so when you scroll it will be 100%.

Comment: Yeah without content which would be lorem ipsum for now.

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: http://www.markclaxton.co.uk/test/ is a link to what i'm working on. As you can see when you scroll down the sidebar does not go to the bottom.

Comment: Viewport units could also easily accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

Set the **height: 100%** and remove **min-height** setting from **#wrapper**. Apply **min-height: 100%** to the divs that you would like to fill the browser.

[**Similar example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zitrusfrisch/Sa6cb/3/)

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin:0;
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is simply using CSS:

```
height: 100vh;
```

Where 'vh' stands as vertical height of the browser window. 
This makes it responsive to resizing of brower and mobile devices.